# Highlighting rows based on the absence of another row

Tags: excel

I have a data Sheet that I need to highlight rows based on certain conditions

I have been successful in highlighting duplicate rows using the following formula in conditional formatting:

```
=COUNTIFS(Employee_Col,$D1,Job_Col,$E1,Date_Col,$F1)>1
```

and applying it to all the cells in the data sheet

```
Employee_Col refers to the emp_ID
```

Job_Col refers to the job_ID

I have created named ranges for the columns in question as per above

I have a separate sheet(Employees) which includes and emp_ID and a type column where I can specify if they are a "Supervisor"

What I'm trying to accomplish is to highlight rows in my Data sheet where I have entries(rows) emp_ID, job_ID, Date but there is no entry for a job_ID, Date combination for an employee designated as a "Supervisor" from the Employee sheet

In other words if there are regular employee entries for a given job and date but no corresponding supervisor employee entry then I would like to highlight the regular employee entries for this given job/date combination

The emp_ID, job_ID, Date entries in the Data sheet can appear anywhere in the Data i.e. they are not necessarily adjacent(by job_id/Date) to one another.

"Supervisor" entries can be added to the Employee sheet at any time so I need the highlighting provided by the conditional formatting to be reflected automatically in the Data sheet.

Hope I'm clear with my intentions, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Adding Screenshots to help explain my intentions...

From the Employee sheet employees 1, 4 and 6 are designated as "Supervisor" in column D

The Highlighted rows in Data_Before_After is the result I'm looking for.

The rows highlighted have no corresponding "Supervisor" entry for the indicated Date and Job

Perhaps I need a helper column that performs the INDEX/MATCH lookup on the Employee sheet to get employees who are supervisors and use that column as well in the conditional formatting.

Just not sure how to get there.

If it can't be done in excel is there a VBA solution?
Thanks again.

[Data_Before_After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktWye.jpg)
[Employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3JBT.jpg)

Comment: This wall of text is really hard to understand. How about posting a screenshot with the BEFORE, then manually enter the AFTER and post that as well. A picture is worth ... Edit your question, post the screenshot link. I'll then edit your question to make it visible.

Comment: Is it too complicated for conditional formatting?